# Decompile C# DLL without method bodies

Tags: c#, dll, decompiling, cil, disassembly

Is there and easy way to decompile a C# DLL (like ILSpy does, for example), but instead of method bodies, have the methods return default values (or throw runtime exceptions for that matter)?

Why do I need this? I am trying to replace some classes in a .dll library. I can't decompile the entire library, since it contains many lambda function and iterators that cause problems when decompiled.

I had, however, success doing this: Copy the decompiled source of the class I want to change, paste it into a new project and include the original .dll as a library. Then, change the class to my liking (change methods implementation for now), and then compile the project and inject the compiled IL code into the original .dll via a disassembler.

This has worked out so far with a success, however now I have run into a problem. The class (let's say `A`) that I'm trying to change now, passes `this` as an argument to other classes (let's say `B`), and it's generating a compile error (since the original `B` class expects the original `A` class, and not the "fake" `A` class that I'm editing).

This, of course, would not be a problem if I had the complete source code to the .dll library, but I don't. Fortunately, I don't have to. If I had a "structure-only" source code (declarations of classes, fields, methods, interfaces and what not, but no method implemetations), I could copy-paste the source of class `A` into this sructure-only sorce code, make the changes I need, compile, and then inject the IL code as before.

So, can I easily get the sructure-only sorce code (again, method implementation can be eighter returning default value, or throwing runtime exception), or is there a better to replace a class in a .dll library like that?

Comment: Decompiling with JetBrains dotPeek would also produce broken code?

Comment: Hm, JetBrains dotPeek doesn't decompile the iterators properly, but I have already fixed that. Nevertheless, I have manually fixed the 90 (or so) error that I had, let's see if it will work.

Comment: @Ignas, when I write custom CIL or Bytecode, JetBrains usually surrenders and inserts a comment like /* compiled code */ where the method body should be.  Redgate on the other hand just crashes.